# how to insert this to mysql if

Tags: php, textfield

Is it possible to insert all the values that the textfield will get if I choose this to generate the textfields. If yes,how? if not is there another way?

```
 <?php
    for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++)
    echo"<input type=text name=textbox id=textbox>";
    ?>
```

tnx in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess your question is how to process the Output of a form with generated textfields?
If you use the code above it will not work because a html id should be unique for an element. So you should change the code to:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++)
    echo"<input type=\"text\" name=\"textbox".$i."\" id=\"textbox".$id."\">";
?>
```

I guess that you know that you need a form element arround your inputs in order to submit them? If you generate the formfields like that you will have all the inputs in the $_POST array(if you submit your form with the post method)

Comment: oh my I didnt thought of this... I guess this will fix my problem(ur code will put different id and name as the loop continue) tnx I know what to do from here :3

Comment: This is not how it should be done. You should assign the variables into an array.

Comment: I disagree with that njk. There is the possibility to use an array but I would only use an array when the data belongs logical together. Iam not sure if this is given here and your solution also doesnt give any advice concerning the ids. Maybe he need different IDs maybe not.

Apart the fact that attribute values always should be quoted!

Answer (score 1):

You would use `$_POST` to get the data; most likely using an array:

```
<input type=text name=textbox[1] />
```

Then prepare your statement and `INSERT` into your database.